# mapbox geojson + leaflet + custom markers

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers

In the geojson file the following can be found for a marker (coming from mapbox geojson)

"marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"monument"}

I would like to find a solution so monument will be monument.png and so the marker can be used/seen in leaflet.

I am wondering if someone already did this before or has an idea how to do this?

```js
var items = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-icgis1jl1","title":"De Bostoren","description":"40 meter hoog, lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"monument"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.628132,52.249322],"type":"Point"},"id":"2011ff2da55dd4d1f6d8b252674517a7"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Josinapark","description":"1929","id":"marker-icgj3dk57","stroke":"#a3e46b","stroke-width":4,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#a3e46b","fill-opacity":0.6000000238418579},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[5.625464,52.251564],[5.624924,52.251493],[5.625308,52.251068],[5.625099,52.25093],[5.625008,52.250745],[5.625195,52.250559],[5.625455,52.25051],[5.626019,52.250646],[5.625826,52.251158],[5.625885,52.251405],[5.625464,52.251564]]],"type":"Polygon"},"id":"2e8117fd2199faacbc43bf022884507b"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id21rbbg3","title":"","description":"","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"5"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.627043,52.247792],"type":"Point"},"id":"3cb601aa00b4514f831bddc5c66ef045"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":" Bomenwandeling ","description":"","stroke":"#008000","stroke-width":5,"stroke-opacity":1},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[5.626421,52.252968],[5.626582,52.253657],[5.62677,52.253717],[5.626882,52.253145],[5.627301,52.253007],[5.627751,52.252958],[5.627682,52.253188],[5.62781,52.253398],[5.627784,52.253526],[5.627607,52.253634],[5.627269,52.253713],[5.62707,52.253868],[5.626652,52.253956],[5.626051,52.254078],[5.625788,52.254122],[5.625689,52.254086],[5.625683,52.253864],[5.625622,52.253744],[5.625726,52.253296],[5.626453,52.253157],[5.62641,52.252969],[5.625238,52.253237],[5.624793,52.252766],[5.623953,52.253004],[5.623291,52.252625],[5.624831,52.252027],[5.625067,52.252053],[5.625445,52.251933],[5.62516,52.251694],[5.625203,52.251516],[5.624914,52.251483],[5.625257,52.25103],[5.625128,52.250951],[5.624989,52.250728],[5.62519,52.250534],[5.625225,52.250286],[5.625311,52.250101],[5.626711,52.249477],[5.626861,52.249326],[5.626936,52.249073],[5.627526,52.249181],[5.62803,52.249368],[5.628148,52.249503],[5.62817,52.249861],[5.628175,52.250091],[5.628567,52.250961],[5.628787,52.250764],[5.630766,52.250242],[5.630841,52.250144],[5.631963,52.250383],[5.632279,52.25124],[5.63222,52.251441],[5.632091,52.251529],[5.631689,52.251618],[5.630058,52.251966],[5.628932,52.252042],[5.628524,52.252029],[5.628261,52.251927],[5.6281,52.251802],[5.628256,52.251378],[5.627467,52.251644],[5.627864,52.252081],[5.628004,52.25237],[5.62779,52.252516],[5.627586,52.252628],[5.627655,52.252699],[5.62641,52.252978]],"type":"LineString"},"id":"3e98e30887b4b75f27f987d79303e0be"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-icgjnwtqb","title":"Museum ( De Tien Malen )","description":"Museum De Tien Malen geeft bezoekers een kijkje in de geschiedenis van putten en omstreken, vanaf de prehistorie tot het heden.","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"m"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.626333,52.251787],"type":"Point"},"id":"408bc766465244a510209d3af55f5712"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-icgivrzl5","title":"De Werkstee","description":"De Werkstee is een een Veluwse schuur met een langwerpige ruimte met open kap en oude balken en een open haard. lees meer ","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"w"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.627735,52.251369],"type":"Point"},"id":"4ddd0901102c2caba84235d739bb654c"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id22srxq0","title":"Driecontinentenbos","description":"Naast de tuinen bestaat het landgoed uit 150 hectare bos. In het Driecontinentenbos groeien coniferen uit Azië, Noord Amerika en Europa. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"b"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.633797,52.246288],"type":"Point"},"id":"54f2d0363c4fd899435bcaea03bd1322"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Arboretum","description":"In deze wat ruimer opgezette bomentuin loopt u over zachte graspaden tussen groene ‘continenten' door. lees meer","id":"marker-icgj7gin8","stroke":"#a3e46b","stroke-width":4,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#a3e46b","fill-opacity":0.6000000238418579},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[5.63008,52.252002],[5.631984,52.251595],[5.632359,52.251464],[5.632327,52.250899],[5.632016,52.250318],[5.631217,52.250098],[5.630954,52.250052],[5.630922,52.25006],[5.630718,52.250114],[5.630085,52.250304],[5.629591,52.250452],[5.629012,52.250643],[5.628728,52.250751],[5.628358,52.25103],[5.628143,52.251391],[5.628046,52.251828],[5.628492,52.252114],[5.63008,52.252002]]],"type":"Polygon"},"id":"6c5a2732dbb38f014f9e9ce853eac47b"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id21yy0p7","title":"Josina park","description":"Aan de overkant van de Gardenseweg ligt, eveneens op het grondgebied van landgoed Schovenhorst, ligt het Josinapark. Het park werd in 1929 beplant. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"3"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.625579,52.250997],"type":"Point"},"id":"7b62c384a7ca41e99121ba6f06393f3f"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id21ym8j6","title":"Kleine Pinetum","description":"Hier begon mr. Schober in 1848 zijn proeftuin en boomkwekerij. Een aantal bomen dat toen is aangeplant, is in die 160 jaar 40 meter hoog gegroeid. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"1"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.627639,52.252127],"type":"Point"},"id":"878b894c9c59cc670e329f1315ef17aa"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id21jly20","title":"Het Speelbos","description":"Hutten bouwen, ravotten en klauteren: het kan allemaal in het Speelbos. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"playground"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.634098,52.250452],"type":"Point"},"id":"8937452b8f8f184031878dd2687e771f"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"","description":"","stroke":"#1087bf","stroke-width":4,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#1087bf","fill-opacity":0.20000000298023224},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[5.633025,52.248942],[5.634613,52.249717],[5.632166,52.250347],[5.631415,52.249533],[5.633025,52.248942]]],"type":"Polygon"},"id":"8a18d375fe6eb11f42a0bc17e5127196"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Grote Pinetum","description":"Het Grote Pinetum werd ingericht omdat er geen plek meer was in het Kleine Pinetum. In 2004 is de proeftuin omgetoverd in ‘De Verborgen Tuin'. lees meer ","id":"marker-icgipkwu0","stroke":"#a3e46b","stroke-width":4,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#a3e46b","fill-opacity":0.4000000059604645},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[5.625316,52.253812],[5.625091,52.254557],[5.628046,52.253703],[5.627982,52.252666],[5.625214,52.253257],[5.625316,52.253812]]],"type":"Polygon"},"id":"8b45212e414a007c3bef3e004b59cfb3"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"","description":"","stroke":"#a3e46b","stroke-width":4,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#3ca0d3","fill-opacity":0.20000000298023224},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[5.634806,52.249756],[5.636951,52.250833],[5.632896,52.251595],[5.632209,52.250373],[5.634806,52.249756]]],"type":"Polygon"},"id":"8bd921c09ee661a40b0108a8e14f592a"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id21xscy5","title":"Arboretum","description":"In deze wat ruimer opgezette bomentuin loopt u over zachte graspaden tussen groene ‘continenten' door. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"4"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.630214,52.251188],"type":"Point"},"id":"92a06a1a933498a6d0041d7f8f48ef68"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-icgiv56c4","title":"Het Koetshuis","description":"Het Koetshuis is ook een officiele trouwlocatie van de gemeente Putten. lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"k"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.626459,52.252278],"type":"Point"},"id":"a20a8298e08b8523be7610313d1483ca"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"marker-id20tceq0","title":"Gratis Parkeren","description":"Parkeren op Landgoed Schovenhorst lees meer","marker-size":"medium","marker-color":"#1087bf","marker-symbol":"car"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[5.632842,52.249572],"type":"Point"},"id":"a5e67eb715cf7d4065322469cf67f3fe"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Cultuurhistorische wandeling","description":"","id":"marker-ici2qx8t0","stroke":"#f86767","stroke-width":5,"stroke-opacity":1},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[5.62765,52.252705],[5.627526,52.252575],[5.626909,52.251976],[5.626341,52.251375]
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry after more searching I found it on this website

```
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
   var smallIcon = L.icon({
                      iconSize: [27, 27],
                      iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                      popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
                      iconUrl: 'leaflet/icons/' + feature.properties.pcp + '.png'
   });

   return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
}
```